# For loop through array.length only executes once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The code below only executes through the first `for` loop once, yet all the other `for` loops perform as expected. Does anyone know why this is the case? I'm not sure how relevant the bulk of the (inefficient, poorly formatted) code within the loop is but I include it nonetheless.

```
var numbers = [9795526789839145, 2861747566959730, 4498854833783559, 6301982162016598, 1131197164065322];
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var current = numbers[i];
    var currentStr = current.toString();
    var reverseStr = currentStr.split('').reverse().join('');
    var reverseArr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < reverseStr.length; i++) {
        reverseArr.push(reverseStr[i]);
    }

    var A = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < reverseArr.length; i += 2) {
        A += Math.round((reverseArr[i]));
    }

    var evenDigits = [];
    for (i = 1; i < reverseArr.length; i += 2) {
        evenDigits.push(reverseArr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < evenDigits.length; i++) {
        evenDigits[i] = evenDigits[i] * 2;
        if (evenDigits[i] > 9) {
            var temp = evenDigits[i].toString();
            var firstInt = Math.round(temp[0]);
            var secondInt = Math.round(temp[1]);
            evenDigits[i] = firstInt + secondInt;
        }
    }

    var B = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < evenDigits.length; i++) {
        B += evenDigits[i];
    }

    var sum = A + B;

    if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        console.log('Yes');
    } else console.log('No');
}
```

Comment: You override the `i` variable inside your `for(i..` loop with another `for(i...) loop`. You should use different variable names, or set them to be local variables (using `var i`).

Comment: @Dekel `var` won't help as both would still be the same variable.

Comment: @vlaz, correct, he must use different names for the iterator-variables.

Comment: @Dekel As the the others say, using `var i` has no effect, but using a different variable to iterate the external loop solves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using same instance of 'i' variable to iterate all loops.

Solution is to use different index variables to iterate external and internal loops

```
var numbers = [9795526789839145, 2861747566959730, 4498854833783559, 6301982162016598, 1131197164065322];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
for (j=0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    var current = numbers[j];
    /...
}
```

JavaScript behaves like this because 'i' is not scoped to block (like in Java od C#). In ES2015 you can use `let` or `const` to bind variable to block scope (in this sample to for loop)